# structure member access - command line

Tags: c++, data-structures

this may be a simple problem, but i am not able to figure it out. I have structure like this.

```
struct emp 
{
  int empid;
  string fname;
}
emp e[10];
```

I have some data in e[10].

```
e[0].empid = 1 , e[0].fname = "tanenbaum"
e[1].empid = 2 , e[1].fname = "knuth"
.....
```

Now if i have given input command line like this:

```
emp , empid
```

Now i need to access the structure emp.empid. If i have 10 other structures, i need to access them, when the input gives like structure tag and structure member.  Here i am not able to figure out how to attach string variables(emp, empid) to structure members(emp.empid). thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
Here is my program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *tag_name = argv[1]; //emp (structure tag name)
  char *member_name = argv[2]; // empid (structure member name)
  int data = argv[3]; //value: 2
  /* I need some mechanism that will convert those tag_name.member_name
     to original structure memmber access

     tag_name(emp).member_name(empid) == value (2)
     Is there any way to map like this
*/
return ;
}
```

Comment: Where is this input command being given? Program arguments on the command line prompt? Some function called internally?

Comment: From command line: emp , empid , 2. Here i need to access the structure elements emp.empid[0....10] and search for value 2. That means i know empid(structure member), emp(structure) and at some variable it has value 2. i need to figure out that emp.empid[0...10] == 2.

Comment: @chrisaycock - from the command line.

Comment: Pls describe clearly. Otherwise, you will get downvotes soon.

Comment: @bjskishore -  what is the difficulty in understanding the question. I am giving structure tag name, and structure member name from the command line. How to access the strucutre tag.strcture member in the program.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a map<> of map<>s, which can be indexed by strings.

Comment: You can not do that in C++ (transform a string into a member/variable name), as variables/names have to be known at compile-time. You can do something like `if(strcmp("empid", someString) == 0) { /* do something with the empid field of a struct */ }` or perhaps use a `map`.

Comment: This sounds like you're just building a database. You might find better luck using one of the many commercial or open-source DBs available rather than trying to build your own relational table look-up routines.

Comment: @chrisaycock - yes you are correct. But very small, very limited focus. can you suggest me any opendb like that.

Comment: @jony: <a href="http://www.sqlite.org/">SQLite</a>

Comment: You can't do "int data = argv[3];" since argv[3] is a char*. To convert it to an int, use atoi(argv[3]). The preferred C++ way would be boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[3]), but I see below that you can't use Boost.

Comment: @jony: +1, Good excercise for me :)

Comment: @jony: I don't mean to sound nasty, but this is the third time you're asking a variation of this question! Please carefully read the answers in your previous questions, you'll find that the responses are the same as below! Carefully study what has been written and if you don't understand something in those answers ask there! People are wasting their time saying the same things again and again and you're clearly not reading the responses properly!

Comment: @NIM : But i got the answer here properly, and in the previous question, i stated clearly that i made mess at my previous question, so i want to give a new try. That's why i asked here. What i got a feeling that my questions are not understandable to all, so i want to give a new try. No offence and i will consider this point also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Using pointer to member operator you can achieve what you wanted.
You need to create small database using std::map.

Below is the working program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct emp 
{
  int empid;
  int salary;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //member map stores member varialbe names and corresponding offsets.
    map<string, int emp::*> memberMap; //It can store offsets of only integer members.

    //tagMap stores tag names and object pointer
    map<string, emp *> tagMap;

    //Allocate for 10 records
    emp *e = new emp[10];
    //Store sample data in those records.
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        e[i].empid = (i+1) * 10;
        e[i].salary = (i+1) * 1000;
    }

    //Populate tag map with tag names and corresponding object pointers
    //As of now, we have only emp structure.
    //You can add more structures similar to below.
    tagMap.insert(pair<string, emp *>("emp", e));

    //Get the offsets of member variables of emp structure.
    int emp::*offset_empid = &emp::empid;
    int emp::*offset_salary = &emp::salary;

    //Populate member map with member names and corresponding offsets
    memberMap.insert(pair<string, int emp::*>("empid", offset_empid));
    memberMap.insert(pair<string, int emp::*>("salary", offset_salary));

    //Am passing tag name in argv[1], member name in argv[2] and record id in argv[3] from
    //command line
    string tagName = argv[1]; //tag name
    string memberName = argv[2]; //member name
    int recordId = atoi(argv[3]);//record id

    //Access member specified like below.
    cout<<"Employee details requested are : "<<endl;
    cout<<memberName<<"\t"<<(tagMap[tagName]+recordId)->*memberMap[memberName];

    //Free the allocated memory.
    delete []e;
}
```

Input:

> emp salary 2

Output:

> Employee details requested are :
>   salary  3000

I hope you can understand the program using comments i wrote.

Input: i am providing tagName, fieldName and recordId.

Output: i am getting the requested field value from requested record id.

Comment: thanks for the program. But i need a generic way, because if i have 30 structures and 20 members of each, coding like above is inefficient. Can you suggest is there any other way using classes and objects. Thanks.

Comment: @jony: Implemented again using map. I hope it helps.

Comment: yes.. i got the answer. But i am not able to understand these points: 1. int emp::*offset_empid = &emp::empid; 2. map<string, int emp::*> memberMap //It can store offsets of only integer members.
Here how to store string values, if the structure has different type of datatypes

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to create the associations in your code.  Parse the input into the structure / field values (e.g. inputstringstream >> structure >> separator >> field), then have something like:

```
if (structure == "emp")
    if (field == "empid")
        ...do something with emp[which_one].empid...
...
```

If you need to separate these steps of resolving the reference from the code that uses the values, then you may wish to have the above code (i.e. the "do something") set a functor that you can call later when you want the actual value.

To provide more structure to essentially the same approach, you could potentially enhance each structure with an API that knows about its fields:

```
struct Emp
{
    // boost::any can directly return an int, string, double etc...
    // you could hack your own union to do this if you needed, or provide
    // some common base class around these types
    boost::any get(const std::string& identifier) const;

    // this one might use std::ostringstream to convert any non-string fields
    // into a textual representation, but e.g. you can loose precision
    // from floating point values
    std::string get(const std::string& identifier) const;
};
```

You could then put the different accessors into one map...

```
struct Field_Access
{
    virtual boost::any get(const std::string& identifier) const = 0;

    virtual bool set(const std::string& identifier, const std::string& value) = 0;
    virtual bool set(const std::string& identifier, const int& value) = 0;
};

struct Emp : Field_Access
{
    ...
};

std::map<std::string, Field_Access*> accessors;

... populate accessors ...
accessors["emp"] = emp;

accessors["emp"][which_one].get("empid");
```

The possibilities are pretty endless, and your question not specific enough to provide very targetted advice.

Comment: can i do this without boost libraries?

Comment: Absolutely. In your EDIT, you say you want to set the values rather than retrieve them. I've edited to illustrate how to overload a set method in Field_Access for each type of field you have, then have that set method only support the related fields.  Or, you can have one set method accepting string, and it can use atoi, istringstream etc to convert values to the type of the specified field.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a base class for your structure handling.  Call it QueryHandlerBase.
2. Derive classes for each type of structure you want to be able to query.  For 'emp' it might be called EmpQueryHandler.
3. Create a map between structure names and the handlers:

`std::map<std::string, QueryHandlerBase *>`

1. Pass the requested structure name to the map to get the pointer to the handler.
2. Pass the requested field name to the handler.  It will be designed to know the fields of that particular structure and do something useful with it (i.e. display the records, etc.).

*EDIT:* Okay here goes...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct emp 
{
  int empid;
  std::string fname;
};

class QueryHandlerBase
{
public:

    virtual void FieldQuery(std::string const &FieldName,
                            std::string const &FieldVal) = 0;

};

class EmpQueryHandler : public QueryHandlerBase
{
public:

    void AddRecord(int empid, std::string const &fname)
    {
        emp x;

        x.empid = empid;
        x.fname = fname;

        m_DataVec.push_back(x);
    }

    virtual void FieldQuery(std::string const &FieldName,
                            std::string const &FieldVal)
    {
        std::vector<emp>::iterator i;
        i = m_DataVec.begin();

        while (i != m_DataVec.end())
        {
            if (FieldName == "empid")
            {
        // do something useful
            }

            if (FieldName == "fname")
            {
                // do something useful
                if ((*i).fname == FieldVal)
                {
                    std::cout << (*i).empid << " " << (*i).fname << std::endl;
                }
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<emp>    m_DataVec;
};


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, QueryHandlerBase *> tables;
    EmpQueryHandler *pEmp = new EmpQueryHandler;

    // make a map entry for your database table
    tables["emp"] = pEmp;

    // populate some records
    pEmp->AddRecord(1, "Bob");
    pEmp->AddRecord(2, "Shiela");
    pEmp->AddRecord(3, "Elroy");
    pEmp->AddRecord(4, "Victoria");

    // perform a query
    tables["emp"]->FieldQuery("fname", "Shiela");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a simple example??

Comment: @jony:  Unfortunately there is nothing simple about it.  Even a synthetic example would be rather lengthy.  We are talking about designing a database engine.  Perhaps if you are open to using an existing dbms, you might want to look into the `sqlite` package.  It is very nicely suited for C and C++ development.

Comment: @Amarddep : No, i am not going to involve deeply like the database engine. SQLite is very huge code to understand. I need just this step, then i designed all the remaining stuff based on this step.

Comment: @jony:  I've added a very simple example.  I hope that helps.